# cv::bitwise_not on cv::Mat matrix

Tags: opencv

I tried to cv::bitwise_not to a cv::Mat matrix of double values. I applied like

```
cv::bitwise_not(img, imgtemp);
```

`img` is `CV_64F` data of 0 and 1. But `imgtemp` has all nonsense data inside.
I am expecting 0 in `img` to be 1 at  `imgtemp` and 1 in `img` to be 0 at  `imgtemp`. How to apply bitwise_not to a double Mat matrix?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot get the sense of doing a bitwise not of a double (floating point) value: you will be doing bitwise operations also on the exponent (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)). All **bits** will be inverted, from 0 to 1 and viceversa.
There is also a note on this aspect in the [function documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20bitwise_not%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20mask%29).

> In case of a floating-point input array, its machine-specific bit
>   representation (usually IEEE754-compliant) is used for the operation.

If you want zeros to become ones and viceversa, as *you* suggested, you could do:

```
cv::threshold(warpmask, warpmaskTemp,0.5,1.0,THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

(see [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#double%20threshold%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20double%20thresh,%20double%20maxval,%20int%20type%29)) (and yes, you can use same matrix for input and destination).

Comment: The documentation says that threshold is for 8bit or 32 bit float, but for me I can confirm it also worked for double. Personally I hate threshold for its half implemented functionality. Having silent code failures took a long time debugging when I started working with 16 bit images.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are either getting the method signature wrong or wrongly named the parameters for the `bitwise_not` method.

According to [OpenCV 2.4.6 Documentation on bitwise_not() method] (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void bitwise_not(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray mask))

```
void bitwise_not(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray mask=noArray())
```

If you are going to use any mask, it needs to be the last argument as mask is an optional for 'bitwise_not' method.

Additionally, all the data types need to be the same in order to avoid confusion. What I am trying to imply is that your source and destination data formats and any interim ones such as the method parameters must be in the same format. You cannot have on ein CV_64F and others in different. If I am not loosing my marbles here, bitwise operation would possibly require you to have all the data in unsigned or signed integer format for the sake of simplicity. Nevertheless, you should have all the types same.

About the garbage that you got, I think it is a general and good programming practice that you initialise your variables with some reasonable values. This helps when you are debugging  step by step and ascertain the details where it failed.

Give it a try.

Comment: No warpmask is the matrix I want to apply bitwise_not. Yes it has 0 and 1 data, but in this case I like to invert its data from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0.

Comment: By the way, if I apply cv::threshold(warpmask, warpmask,0.5,1,THRESH_BINARY_INV); using same Mat at src and dst, is there memory leak? Any idea?

Comment: @batuman        I sincerely recommend that you update the post and use correct parameter names. Your parameter names could be confusing for other users to understand. For the `threshold` function I don't see any immediate danger of using `src` and `dst` the same. However, you have got to be careful not to write to and read from the same location. It is always safer to use different source and destination. If you don't need to retain your `src`, I guess you can do it. I also think you should ask OpenCV at http://answers.opencv.org/ as a parallel of SE.

Answer (score 0):

To follow on from Antonio's answer, you should use the right tool for the job. double is not an appropriate storage medium for boolean data.

In open cv you can type a boolean as an unsigned char (8bits). Although in typing your own true value you can pick any non-zero value, in open cv it is more natural to have 0/255; that way fitting in with open cv's bitwise operations and comparison operators. E.g. a bitwise not could be achieved by `result = (input == 0)` which can take any type. threshold in Antonio's answer maintains the same type (useful in some circumstances). For bitwise_not you should have it in the boolean format first.

Unfortunately opencv makes it very difficult to work with black and white bitwise data.